# Jest Not Displaying Colors, Or Accepting Commands

Tags: windows-7, jestjs, git-bash

I'm running Jest to test a Create React App in a Git-Bash terminal, on Windows 7. It's running the tests as it should; but it isn't displaying the PASS/FAIL messages with color enhancements.

Also, when it asks for a 'u' to update snapshots, it doesn't accept the u. Control-C'ing after trying the u, I see the u as the first command once Jest has stopped running.

Has anyone seen these behaviors before? Any idea how to fix?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `export FORCE_COLOR=true` into your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3877#issuecomment-422088942

Comment: Not certain if this actually works, as I've long since moved from that job, and the environment (i.e. the Win7 laptop) went back to IT.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this with ReactJs App. Go to package.json and add "--colors"

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test --colors",
    },
```

This fixed my issue. Thanks!